# Inheritance having protected class

Tags: java, inheritance

This is a code sample of inheritance while the code functions fine.I am unable to understand the output of this code kindly explain it to me.

```
class R {
    private void S1() {
        System.out.println("R:S1");
    }

    protected void S2() {
        System.out.println("R:S2");
    }

    protected void S1S2() {
        S1();
        S2();
    }
}

class S extends R {
    private void S1() {
        System.out.println("S:S1");
    }

    protected void S2() {
        System.out.println("S:S2");
    }
}

public class Inheritance {
    public static void main(String srgs[]) {
        new S().S1S2();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
R:S1
S:S2
```

Why is the first call made to,R class' S1 while second to S class' S2.

Comment: Main is right there. Not a Homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.S1` is *private*, so it's not called polymorphically, and `S.S1` doesn't override it.

`R.S2` is *protected*, so `S.S2` overrides it, and when you call `S2` on an instance of `S2` (even if it's only *statically* known to be an instance of `R`), `S.S2` will be called.

From [section 8.4.8.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
> - Either:
>
>   - m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same package as C, or
>   - m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2), such that m3 overrides m2.

Note how `m2` can't be private.

Comment: So S.S2 overrides R.S2 .That explains why changing the access modifier of R.S2 to private would produce the desired result.Thank you Jon

Answer (score 0):

In R, S1 is private and so cannot be overridden. The call to S1 in R#S1S2 therefore always calls R#S1. The S1 in S is totally unrelated. [Side note: you need better names.]

But S2 is not private so it can be overridden - and it is.

Java VMs can get good performance gains out of knowing that private functions cannot be overridden. And nothing, not even a descendant class, should be affected by the private details of a class.

Comment: Yes I got that now. And yeah I do need better names. Thank you